# Cannot update Ubuntu due to broken package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I run software updater I get

> The Package system is broken
>   Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
>   Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`

That command entry returns with

```
$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0):

that is because both you are running it without sudo, and the previous package operation failed and has thus not released its hold on the installation directory. Reboot and run "sudo apt-get -f install"